# To find isomorphism,Not automorphism in complex field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

While studying abstract algebra, I looked mostly an automorphism of field in $\mathbb{C}$  through examples of books.
In field theory, I want to find an example of Isomorphism, not Automorphism in complex field.But it did not come easy.

My idea is this.

$1.$ the rational field $\mathbb{Q}$ is perfect field, so  its extension field is a separble over $\mathbb{Q}$.

$2.$ To find an isomorphism $\psi : \mathbb{F}$->$\mathbb{F'}$ ( Both $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbb{F'}$ be different for each other and subfield of $\mathbb{C}$

$3.$ If both fields are splitting field of {$f(x)$} over $\mathbb{Q}$, By the conjugate isomorphism theorem, there exists an isomorphism between two field.

$4.$ But that's not what I'm looking for. Since it may be an automorphism.

$5.$ So should we use other theorems, Not conjugate isomorphism theorem ?

I may be thinking hard about the easy questions. I would like a lot of advice.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327901/isomorphisms-between-mathbb-c-and-field-mathbb-k) might be slightly useful.

Comment: @Mark thanks, And while I was studying, I found the answer I wanted in splitting field of x^4-2 over Q.